# Pooled OLS versus Fixed Effects

Tags: stata, least-squares, fixed-effects-model

I have an unbalanced panel data and I run a pooled ols and my results are fine. But when I do the diagnostics, linktest and ovtest fails. I then do Hausman to compare between ols and fixed effect. I am able to reject the null.
However with fixed effects, my results aren't significant. I make yline graphs to see if there is enough variation in my main regressor, there isn't much. Could that be causing the insignificance. How do I solve the problem. Any other estimation ideas or suggestions?
I am an undergrad student and I haven't done more advanced methods yet. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show us the outputs from both models?